# Show that $\mathcal{M}_1 := \{Y \cap E\ | Y \in \mathcal{M}\}$ is an infinite $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that given an infinite $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ we have that $\mathcal{M}_1 := \{Y \cap E\ | Y \in \mathcal{M}\}$ is an infinite $\sigma$-algebra.

Also I don't think the infinite part is needed..

There is a slight variation of the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891313/does-the-intersection-of-an-infinite-sigma-algebra-with-the-complement-of-an/2891346?noredirect=1#comment5971812_2891346) (It is really the same question though) but in the answer, they say

> 2. If $F \in M_1$, then $F = G \cap E^c$ for some $G \in M$. So, $G^c \cap E^c \in M_1$ as well, and $(G \cap E^c) \cup (G^c \cap E^c) = E^c \implies M_1$ is closed under complements.

But don't we need that $F^c$ is in $\mathcal{M_1}$ not $E^c$ in order to say it is closed under compliments? I am confused about this...

**I tried to show** if $F$ is in $\mathcal{M_1}$ then $F=G\cap E$ for some fixed G in $\mathcal{M}$ then we have $F^c=(G\cap E)^c=G^c \cup E^c$ but I am not sure how to show that this is in $\mathcal{M_1}$.

Thanks!

Comment: What is  $E$?...

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say. E is a subset of M.

Comment: No. It is an _element_ of $\mathcal M$. Also, the claim is obviously false. If, e.g., $E=\emptyset$, then $\mathcal M_1$ consists of one element, namely the empty set.

Comment: As to your last question: $G$ and $E$ are in $\mathcal M$, hence so are $G^c$ and $E^c$ and also their union.

Comment: BTW: Why do you open up a second question which is identical to your first one?

Comment: @amsmath I just had a question on my previous question and I know from using this site that people just prefer if I open a new question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also a little confused about that part of the answer to your previous question. Let's try a different approach.

We want to show that $\mathcal{M}_1$, as a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$,  is closed under complements. This means that if $F \in \mathcal M_1$, then $E \setminus F \in \mathcal M_1$.

Suppose $F \in \mathcal M_1$. There exists some $Y \in \cal M$ such that $F = Y \cap E$. We thus have that $$E \setminus F = E \setminus Y = Y^c \cap E.$$ Since $Y$ is in $\cal M$, so is $Y^c$, which then means that $E \setminus F \in \mathcal M_1$.